# Union Multiple Text Files

Tags: windows, text-processing

So is there a software to `union` (not simple merge, that is duplicate lines will be removed) multiple text file one after another to a single big file?

I need it for a research purpose. No GUI required.

Thanks.

Comment: If I recall my database lectures correctly, that's more a `join` instead of a `union`

Comment: How does the accepted solution remove duplicate lines?

Comment: Following up on earlier remarks: your question is ambiguous, please [edit] it. Does *that is* refer to the 'union' or to the 'simple merge', i.e. do you want duplicate lines removed or not? It is not even clear if you want the result file sorted (and also, are your input files sorted? - that may make a difference for the possible results). It helps if you give an example of two input files + one output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.filesplitter.org as long as your files have the same name and extension .chunk001 etc

And then use Notepad++ to remove the duplicate lines, as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16293580/8157

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allergic to ports of unix tools, use http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ and then do

> sort.exe -u file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > output

This will destroy the ordering, but with omitting duplicated lines is going to be slightly messy anyway.